# What are good ways to load kinect input into unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

I'd like to design a simple tower defense game, with the twist that every input is done via the Kinect. I want to give the player the option to build a real maze and project the minions on it via beamer.

The input from the Kinect should mainly be range data and color data. I'm at the beginning of the Project and up till now I only found Kinect fusion which seems to have the functionality I need.

Can you suggest any other options, which I should take a look at?

Comment: Please don't use unity tag, on SO unity3d tag is used for Unity3d game engine questions.

Comment: This might be a better question for https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/